# Passing function to html in php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to replicate a function and pass it to the body of my site but it's not even loading the header for some reason and I think it's because something isn't being passed correctly.

This works with another function from the same file in almost the exact same format. The only difference is the working function uses `$_SESSION[dealernum]` and the function I'm trying to get doesn't have a session variable and it's using select option from a drop down `$swrapper->getRepNum()`.

Here's the function I'm trying to get to load:

```
private function loadPlacement($custno){
    $custno += 0;
    $this->mysqlConnect();

    $sql1 = " SELECT count(dealer_id), start_date as period, sum(placements), sum(pieces)
            FROM placements p
            inner join dealers d
            on p.dealer_id = d.dealer_num
             WHERE d.sales_rep = {$custno}
             and p.start_date between '{$this->py_from}' and '{$this->py_thru}'
           ";

        $result1 = mysql_connect($this->mysqli, $sql1);

        $this->placeSnap = array();

        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
            $this->placeSnap[$row1['PERIOD']] = round($row1['placements'],0);
            $this->isloaded = true;
        }

        if ($this->placeSnap['PY_YTD'] == 0) {
            $this->placeSnap['PCT'] = 0;
        } else {
            $this->placeSnap['PCT'] = ($this->placeSnap['CY_YTD']-$this->placeSnap['PY_YTD']) / $this->placeSnap['PY_YTD'];
            $this->placeSnap['PCT'] = round( $this->placeSnap['PCT'] * 100, 0);
            $this->placeSnap['PCT'] = min(array($this->placeSnap['PCT'], 999));
        }
    }


/**
 * HTML for placement snapshot table
 * 
 * @param int $custno
 * @param string $header
 * @return string
 */
function getPlacementSnapshotHTML($custno, $header='Placement Snapshot') {

    $this->loadPlaceSnap($custno);

    $h1 = "<table class='customer-volume-snapshot-table'>";
    $h1 .= "<thead><tr><th colspan='2'>" . htmlspecialchars($header) . "</th></tr></thead>";
    $h1 .= "<tbody>";
    $h1 .= "<tr><td>{$this->pyyy} YTD</td><td style='text-align: right;'>$" . number_format($this->placeSnap['PY_YTD']) . "</td></tr>";
    $h1 .= "<tr><td>{$this->yyyy} YTD</td><td style='text-align: right;'>$" . number_format($this->placeSnap['CY_YTD']) . "</td></tr>";
    $h1 .= "<tr><td>Percent Change</td><td style='text-align: right;'>{$this->salessum['PCT']}%</td></tr>";
    $h1 .= "<tr><td>{$this->pyyy} Full Year</td><td style='text-align: right;'>$" . number_format($this->placeSnap['PY_FULL']) . "</td></tr>";
    $h1 .= "</tbody></table>";

    return $h1;
}
```

And here's the HTML where I'm trying to load it:

```
if(!empty($swrapper->getRepNum())){
    echo "<table><td>";
    echo "Rep Number {$swrapper->getRepNum()}"; //This is loading the rep number correctly
    $h1 = $custdash->getPlacementSnapshotHTML($swrapper->getRepNum(), "Placement Snapshot For Rep {$swrapper->getRepNum()}"); //This is not loading at all
    echo "<div style='border: 1px solid black; margin: 3px; padding: 3px;'>";
    echo "</table></td>";

}
```

The echo of the rep number shows up but nothing for the function. Maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: you never echo the return of that function `getPlacementSnapshotHTML`!

Comment: maybe this is what you want: replace `$h1 = $custdash->...` with `echo $custdash->...`

Comment: Not sure what `$this->loadPlaceSnap($custno);` call does, because in your code you shown us a function called `loadPlacement($custno);` (And you never call that function in your example) so I wonder if you're calling the correct function in the class. Please explain what your code supposed to do

Comment: I believe that's right, I just corrected that but still no loading. Basically, the loadplacement function is using that query to acquire the data I need for sales reps and then the second function just structures the HTML for it based on the rep number

Comment: @TomN. You're also trying to fetch a column named `placements` but in your query you don't select that column - You select `sum(placements)`. You need to name that column `sum(placements) as placements_sum` (for example), and then instead of `$row1['placements']` you change it to `$row1['placements_sum']`. The same goes for `$row1['PERIOD']`, not sure it indexes are case sensitive so use `$row1['period']` instead

Comment: Ah, great point. I fixed those up as well. That makes sense for the data portion of the function, but I would think even if there was an error in the function it would pass the title

Comment: We need to see the body of the `$swrapper->getRepNum()` function. As pointed out - You're only saving it to a variable `$h1` but I don't see where you actually `echo` it. Also - You're calling that function multiple times, so it's better the save the returned value of that function in a variable and then use it in the `if` statement and when you're passing it to   `$custdash->getPlacementSnapshotHTML()`  and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like this

```
echo "Rep Number ".$swrapper->getRepNum();
$h1 = $custdash->getPlacementSnapshotHTML($swrapper->getRepNum()."Placement Snapshot For Rep ".$swrapper->getRepNum()); //This is not loading at all
            echo "<div style='border: 1px solid black; margin: 3px; padding: 3px;'>";
```

it will print the return values